# Weird formatting issue in hadoop map/reduce program in java

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a csv file with following sample records.

```
| publisher  | site               | ad clicks | ad views |
|============|====================|===========|==========|
| publisher1 | www.sampleSite.com |        50 |       75 |
| publisher1 | www.sampleSite2.com|        10 |       40 |
| publisher2 | www.newSite1.com   |       100 |      175 |
| publisher2 | www.newSite2.com   |        50 |       65 |
```

Using map/reduce in java, I am trying to sum all ad clicks and ad views for every publisher. So output should be like this

```
publisher1 60, 115
publisher2 150, 240
```

I have written following code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class SGSClickViewStats
{
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> 
    {
        int recNo = 0;
        private Text publisherName = new Text();
        private Text mapOpValue    = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text inputs, OutputCollector <Text, Text> output, Reporter rptr) throws IOException{
            String line = inputs.toString();
            String [] fields = line.split(",");
            String pubName = formatStats(fields[0]);
            String click   = fields[2];
            String views   = fields[3];
            // ***** send stats to reducer as a string separated by :
            String value   = click+":"+views;

            mapOpValue.set(formatStats(value));
            publisherName.set(pubName);   

            output.collect(publisherName, mapOpValue);
        }

        private String formatStats(String stat) {
            while((stat.indexOf("\"") >= 0) && (stat.indexOf(",")) >= 0){
                stat = stat.replace("\"","");
                stat = stat.replace(",","");
            }
            return stat;
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer< Text, Text, Text, Text >
    {
        private Text pubName = new Text();
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> oc, Reporter rptr) throws IOException {
            int views     = 0;
            int clicks    = 0;
            String val    = "";
            String opVal  = "";
            Text textOpVal= new Text();

            while(value.hasNext()){
                val = value.next().toString();

                String [] tokens = val.split(":");

                try {
                    clicks = clicks + Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
                    views  = views  + Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("This is Command HQ, code red\nError Message: "+e.getLocalizedMessage()+" Error class: "+e.getClass()+"Extra, Array length: "+tokens.length);
                }
            }           

            try {
                            // ******* want to separate stats by comma but can't !!
                opVal = Integer.toString(clicks) + ":"+ Integer.toString(views);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("This is Command HQ, code Yellow\nError Message: "+e.getLocalizedMessage()+" Error class: "+e.getClass());
            }
            textOpVal.set(opVal);
            oc.collect(key, textOpVal);     
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf jc = new JobConf(SGSClickViewStats.class);
        jc.setJobName("SGSClickViewStats");
        jc.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        jc.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        jc.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        jc.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        jc.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);

        jc.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        jc.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jc, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jc, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(jc);
    }
}
```

This program is working fine, but in output of reducer, I can't have final stats separated by a comma, which is at second comment with ********. If I do that, all my stats become 0, 0. I get this error when I try to comma separate.

```
Error Message: For input string: "50, 75" 
Error class: class java.lang.NumberFormatExceptionExtra, Array length: 1
```

Array length is length of tokens array in reducer function, as I am sending output from mapper to reducer colon (:) separated tokens should have 2 elements, I see one when I set output of reducer comma separated.

I have referred many articles, but I couldn't find an answer. 
I sincerely hope that someone helps !! :)

Comment: In which line does the error occur? Is it in the first try or the second? Because NumberFormatException is thrown by Integer.parseInt.

Comment: @Tudor: It appears at first try block.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: epic in what ways? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NumberFormatException` is definitely thown by `Integer.parseInt`, so your error must be in the first try when you are computing the clicks and views sum. Check the output passed by the mapper. I'm pretty sure you are not formatting the strings correctly in the mapper.

**Edit**: To make it clear for future readers: the problem was the usage of the Reducer class also as a Combiner by mistake, thus producing a different output than expected from the map phase.

Comment: I have checked mapper output. It's something like this: `publisher1 50:75`. So it is correctly colon separated. I also saw input of reducer, it is the same as passed by mapper. If u saw the error message, it is showing `error in input string "50, 75"`. And this error message I generated in reducer. Input from mapper comes in colon separated format. So where on earth does that `50, 75` value comes from?

Comment: Well have a look at the formatStats method, it only replaces if there is a slash AND a comma. In the string seems only to be a comma but no slash. So he can either change AND to OR, or just use replaceAll() without the checks.

Comment: slash? No, I am trying to replace double quotes and comma. Yeah but I got what you are saying. But the thing is that, error appears at reducer. As mentioned in my above comment, output from mapper is correctly, as intended, in colon separated format.

Comment: Oh sorry it was escaped^^. However, the mapoutput is always the reducer input. There is no transformation in between from the framework. So the problem must be in your code.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you checked the mapper output? Because it seems to me like you are getting something like "publisher1 50, 75:" So in either clicks or views you get the full string "50, 75".

Comment: yes I eventually came to know, that mapper's output is passed as is, to reducer. But still this happens. For simplicity, I took only 2 records and observed logs. There I found output of mapper is colon separated but value received by reducer has comma in it. It is simply bewildering. I am very much new to Hadoop and map/reduce, so with whatever little I have learned about it, I am coding. But this problem simply escapes me!!

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, I have gone through code again and again, only to fail to understand what could be the problem. Can you please have a look at the code patiently and suggest me something? because, everything goes smoothly. Just when I change reducer output from colon separated to comma separated, everything wrongs. It's like this comma separated output is again fed to reducer, so it has difficulty to split it by colon and then in pasrseInt it fails.

Comment: Shit, you have a combiner. So this means the reducer code is run twice! Try to remove the line jc.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);

Comment: yes yes, what the hell is that line useful for when I don't have a combiner class. You just taught me one more concept. ohhh hell yeah..you guys are freakin' awesome!! Thank you very much !! :D

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using your Reducer as combiner?
By the time you data come to Reduce phase it is already "publisher\tclicks,views" format
I guess that could be causing problem.

Can you comment following line and check?

```
jc.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
```

Comment: yes it was the same problem. I removed that part and it was done. Thanks for your help!